# UE4: Set texture to material (C++)

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm new to unreal coding, I want to apply texture to material, but I'm stuck with creating:

```
    UMaterialInterface* Material = CreateDefaultSubobject<UMaterial>(TEXT("MyMaterial"));
    UMaterialInstanceDynamic* DynamicMatierial = UMaterialInstanceDynamic::Create(Material, this);
```

I've got this error message:

NewObject with empty name can't be used to create default subobjects (inside of UObject derived class constructor) as it produces inconsistent object names. Use ObjectInitializer.CreateDefaultSuobject<> instead.

This error comes from second line. Any idea why this error occurs? **Or is there any other easy way to apply texture to material?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 4 days of searching I've found correct answer to my texture problem in this post:

https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/46406-how-to-initialize-umaterial-and-assign-texture-to-it#post466817

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've solved this error, this line of can't be used in constructor:

```
UMaterialInstanceDynamic* DynamicMatierial = UMaterialInstanceDynamic::Create(Material, this);
```

Move it to PostLoad or other lifecycle method